# Compose music in Reason, synced up to a project in Premiere

Tags: sync, reason, premiere

I have a movie in Premiere which I want to give a soundtrack. For this, I would like Reason to sync up with Premiere, so that I for example can put that epic etnodrum solo at the exact right time, or change the order of the clips to better fit the music. Basically, I would like for Reason and Premiere to sync up so that when one of the program is running, the other one is to, at the same place in the timeline.

From my understanding, Premiere does not support ReWire, so that won't be an option.

Comment: I havent ever heard of a way to sync up NLEs with Audio programs nor do i think it would be possible. Unless Reason indicates that their software works with Adobe's (or vise versa) then I think you are out of luck

Comment: Vegas Pro allows to have simultaneous multiple sound and video tracks to sync. But this is the same NLE, haven't heard of 2 different NLE's working simultaneously either. It sure would be easier if you could import your audio from Reason to Premiere ? Why can't you have reason convert the desireed audio track to a .wav, save this then import to Premiere, trim in timeline to get it lined up the way you want it?

Comment: @filzilla: I want to compose on the go, simultaneously with the editing of my video. I want to be able to rearrange the music to fit with the video and to rearrange the video to fit with the music. I also would like to use Reason to edit all my sounds instead of having to work in Premiere with this. So there are a lot of reasons (for me wanting to use Reason).

Answer (score 3):

http://www.propellerheads.se/products/reason/index.cfm?article=rewire&fuseaction=get_article

This is a list of software that is compatible with Reason's Rewire. since it's not on that list, it's not possible, at least not in any sort of convenient way.

Rewire does work with Audition but I'm not familiar with this software. If Audition syncs with premier you might be able to create some sort of chain. If you have Audition it might be worth a shot. Setting up Rewire is as easy as starting the programs in the right order, at least in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

[Retouch](http://www.retouchcontrol.com/site_page.aspx?pageid=46). The only solution so far I've seen around but havent tried yet

From the website...

> **Overview**
>
> Ever wanted to sync video to Reason without needing to
>   Rewire? Now you can!
>
> **ReSync** allows you to open any QuickTime supported video and syncs its
>   playback to the Reason transport! Use the transport control buttons in
>   Reason or even move the playhead with the mouse to scrub the playback,
>   your music and video will stay in sync.
>
> **ReSync** opens any supported video in its native resolution size.
>   However, you can resize the video window to any size you want,
>   including full screen. Also, ReSync offers full control over the
>   video's audio with dedicated "Mute" and "Volume" controls.